# Filter an array of objects within an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following;

```
var room = function(){
    this.entities = new Array();
}
var myRoom = new room();
```

I also have a bunch of entites like this;

```
var entity = function(){
    this.title = "A pillow";
    this.noun = "pillow";
}
```

I can push many entities into the myRoom.entities array.

Now I want to check to see whether a room contains a particular entity based on its noun.

I've tried something like this;

```
var objPillow = myRoom.filter(function (object) { return object.entities.noun == "pillow" });
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you pushing entities into `myRoom.entities`? What does “doesn’t work” mean?

Comment: Why did you remove the second example of what you've tried from your question?

Comment: I removed it because it did work and I was alerting it out wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your phrase "Now I want to **check to see whether a room contains a particular entity based on its noun**.", so you don't need the entity itself, but to check for its existence:

```
function check(noun){
  return myRoom.entities.some(function(a){ return a.noun === noun; })
}

var sample = new Entity();
sample.noun = "Test";
sample.title = "Anything";

myRoom.entities.push(sample);

check("Test"); //>>true
```

Comment: Actually that's fits better with my question but both you and @net.uk.sweet have helped solve the issue.  and yeah, based on my phrasing this is more correct.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript `filter` is an array method (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)). You should call it on the `entities` property of your object instead:

```
var objPillow = myRoom.entities.filter(function (entity) { 
  return entity.noun == "pillow" 
});
```

Comment: Erm, yes.  Missed that one.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry but based on my phrasing of the question the other answer is more correct though i will also be using this answer.  thanks again.

Comment: That's cool. I went straight to the code, Alcides read and understood the question.